# How to build an $in query of ObjectIds using QueryBuilder with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, query-builder

I am trying to build an $in query with QueryBuilder (MongoDB Java API 2.9.1).  I have no problem when the query is an array of strings but when I try with an array of ObjectIds it doesn't work (returns nothing).

I am able to run the query successfully and get a result from the console:

Query in console:
db.collection.find({removed:false,app_id: {$in : [ObjectId("4f75c533ac99d845186e19b2"), ObjectId("4f75c533ac99d845186e19b3")]}})

Query created by QueryBuilder (MongoDB Java API 2.9.1):

Object[] ids;

Java code:
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("app_id").in(ids).and("removed").is(false).get();

ToString on DBObject produces:
{ "app_id" : { "$in" : [ { "$oid" : "4f75c533ac99d845186e19b2"}]} , "removed" : false}

Not sure if I am doing something wrong or the API doesn't support and $in query of type ObjectId.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but you're using "application_id" in the shell and the `ToString` output is showing "app_id".

Comment: Sorry the toString output is correct.  It should read app_id instead of application_id.  I will update the question.

Comment: In your console query, you have two objectids in your array, but when you're running it in your Java code, you only have one object id, so maybe that's why nothing is matching the query. Is this a typo? Try printing out your ids array, are you passing the right thing into your .in() ? Is this a typo ?

Comment: Both objectIds will match so the result size will be different but the query return a result which it does not.

Comment: Both objectIds will match so the result size will be different but the query should return a result which it does not.
What I left out is if you run the query but instead of using ObjectIds app_id is of type string then the query works.

Answer (score -2):

Your ids should be of type `org.bson.types.ObjectId` so something like this should work:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

ObjectId[] ids = new ObjectId[]{
  new ObjectId("1234568abcd"), 
  new ObjectId("1234567abcd")};

DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("app_id").in(ids)
  .and("removed").is(false).get();
```